# How do I display the contents of find in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

[I tried running this script to display the total files required in a directory but it did not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4xb.jpg)

```
echo "please enter your directory: "
Read directory 
Echo -e "Please enter your project name: "
Read projName
find $directory -type f -name ' $projName ' -exec du -ch {} + | while read file; do 
echo "Reading $file"
Echo $file | grew total$
```

Comment: Could you please be so polite and read the [tour] (as requested), so you know what the site is about? If you don't care about spending a little time on that, and on properly formatting your question, you might not be a the right place to contribute to a quality Q&A site. We're not some helpdesk that gets paid to make your posts acceptable.

Comment: I don't understand why you are running `read file` -- you should add some explanation of what you're trying to achieve however

Comment: Sorry, I am both new to Linux shell scripting and also to this platform. Will improve. This is the issue I have, I want to run a script that can calculate the sum of space used by a group of files in a folder when a user inputs the path and the file names using wild card. Pls help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "did not work"?

Here are some issues with your script:

**Original**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter directory: "
read directory
echo -e "Please enter project name: "
read projName
find $directory -type f -name ' $projName ' -exec du -ch {} + | while read file; do
echo "Reading $FILE..."
echo $FILE | grep total$
done
```

**Updated**

```
#! /bin/bash -
read -p "Please enter a directory: " directory    # Shorter
read -p "Please enter a project name: " projName    # Shorter
find "$directory" -type f -name "$projName" | while read file; do #Always double quote your variables.  The single quotes around projName prevented it from being expanded.
echo "Reading $file..."  # $FILE is not a valid variable in your script
du -ch "$file"          # this being in an exec statement was feeding bad info to your while loop.
cat "$file" | grep 'total$'   # $FILE is not a valid variable in your script.  I think you want to cat the contents of the file and not echo it's filename.
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to list the entire size of an directory:

`du -c` will give you one 'grand total' figure at the end in bytes.

`du -ck` will give you one 'grand total' figure at the end, in kilobytes  (approx).

**Note**: both the above give you the file size for every file, followed by the grand total.
If you don't want every files size then use `-s`

`du -sk` will give you just a 'grand total' figure, in kilobytes (approx).

Answer (score 0):

```
find <pathtodirectory> -name '$projName' -exec du -ch '{}' \; | awk '/total/ { tot=+$1 } $0 !~ "total" { print "Reading "$2"...\n" } END { print "Space "tot"\n"}'
```

Use awk to parse your output. If the text contains the text total, set total to the second space delimited field otherwise set the file name to the first delimited piece. Then at the end, print the data in the format you wish.

Comment: This almost does the trick. Thanks you, however, it's giving the total of each file, what I need is for the script to give a single total of all the files selected. Thank you so much

Comment: No worries, I have changed accordingly